# Javascript code required for refering a JS file depends on the environment Prod, Dev, stage

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, window.location

I want to check Prod, dev and QA URL based on the URL i need to refer a .js file

Production URL: domain.com and www.domain.com

i should refer: src=prod.js file if the URL is production url

Dev and QA URLs: dev.domain.com and staging.com

i should refer: src= staging.js file if the URL is dev or QA or both,

I wish to use this window.location.href.search using if else condition.

Please help me with the if else condition using javascript.

---

I tried the with the below code but it is not working

```
if (window.location.href.search("domaing.com")!=-1 && window.location.href.search("staging.vicodin.com"|"dev.domain.com)==-1) { 
        src=prod.js
} 
else{
src=staging.js
}
```

Please help me to have the correct code

Comment: You're missing a `"` after `dev.domain.com`.

Comment: It have include " as you said but it is not referring. Could you please  help me to have the correct code. I am unsure whether the code is correct or not

Comment: I think you may need to detail what exactly you're doing with the "src" variable in your code once it's been set. What you've provided isn't enough to determine the exact way you're going about this.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with your condition:

1. You haven't closed a string (missing `"` after dev.domain.com)
2. You use the [bitwise or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) operator instead of the [logical or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) (| instead of ||)
3. You expect f(a||b) to do the same as f(a) || f(b)
4. You haven't set the values of src as strings (prod.js instead of "prod.js")

Here is a correct solution:

```
if (window.location.href.search("domaing.com") !== -1 && 
    (window.location.href.search("staging.vicodin.com") === -1 ||
    window.location.href.search("dev.domain.com") === -1)) { 
    src = "prod.js";
} else{
    src = "staging.js";
}
```